# ¿Aguien ha usado gridjs y pudo cambiar el theme?

Tags: css

Alguien que usa o ha usado gridjs y me puede decir si hay themes que no sea el mermaid.css para que pueda descargar?

Mucha gracias

Comment: Recordá formular tus preguntas en base a [ask], además de que [es.so] **no es un foro**. Para este tipo de preguntas, podrías acudir al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).

Comment: ahh, gracias por la aclaracion.